# spark streaming dataframe query is stuck

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to read the data from kafka topic into spark streaming dataframe and write it to console.

```
df = spark.readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "my_host:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "my_topic") \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load()
```

then the query is

```
query = df.writeStream \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .trigger(processingTime="10 seconds") \
  .format("console") \
  .start().awaitTermination()
```

after running this block i see the indication

`[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 8]`

and nothing happens even if i send the messages to the topic (i've sent about 60 messages 256 bytes each).
Then after some timeout it throws an exception:

```
23/05/20 15:59:13 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
23/05/20 15:59:13 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source write support org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWrite@11225b86 is aborting.
23/05/20 15:59:13 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source write support org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWrite@11225b86 aborted.
23/05/20 15:59:13 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = c49aca99-a844-4c90-93ac-461d520ac43d, runId = 9c4525a0-09d4-46d9-86de-bcb3a389b35c] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.writingJobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:613)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3715)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collect$1(Dataset.scala:2971)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3706)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2971)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:603)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:598)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:598)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:228)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:303)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:209)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 9) (172.31.4.228 executor 0): org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition scraping-google1-0 could be determined

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:354)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition scraping-google1-0 could be determined
```

Could you please tell what am i doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you checked , whether IP for the broker is correct or not
And also , Either remove the assignment after await() or do await separately  on QUERY 
`query = df......start()
query.awaitTermination()`

Comment: the ip is correct
and i've tried the await perarately - the result is the same

Comment: Ive tried the exact same code in my env, and its working fine, Might be some issue with Kafka broker, Check Broker , try to run one console consumer using KAFKA
`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

Comment: The error is saying it's timing out from Spark executors to kafka... What debugging have you done? Such as running above command?